# Count element in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have one problem with PHP array. I have the following array:

```
$arr = array(
  1 => array(1, 2),
  2 => array(1,2,3),
  3 => array(4,array(4,4,4))
);
```

I want to know how many element in total.
Ex:

```
echo count($arr); // result: 3
```

but I want: 7

I want to do this without loop.

Do any one know, please help?

Comment: Can you explain where are the 7 elements?

Comment: Hi! I want to count the element inside $arr. First index: 2 elements, Second index: 3, and Third index: 2 elements. Total is 7. How to get this?

Comment: Can you tell use more about what you want exactly? You are trying to count only 2 dimensions array and third nested array which is inside third index is ignored. The problem's there. Without loop I have no idea.

Comment: [Php recursive array counting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18429958/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take one of this

```
$arr = array(
    1 => array(1, 2),
    2 => array(1, 2, 3),
    3 => array(4, array(4, 4, 4))
);

// iterate over values to find out their size/
var_dump(array_reduce($arr, function($count, $inner_array)
        { return $count + sizeof($inner_array); }, 0));

// merge all value to one big array
var_dump(count(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arr)));

// create new array with counts of items    
var_dump(array_sum(array_map('sizeof', $arr)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$arr = array(
  1 => array(1, 2),
  2 => array(1,2,3),
  3 => array(4,array(4,4,4))
);

$sum = 0;

foreach($arr as $a => $b) {
    $sum += count($b);
}   

echo $sum;

?>
```

Comment: In fact, we can do this. But I don't want to use loop. Do we have other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array(
  1 => array(1, 2),
  2 => array(1,2,3),
  3 => array(4,array(4,4,4))
);

$count = 0;
foreach ($arr as $level) {
    $count+= count($level);
}
echo $count;
```

If your array as follows you can use another method for get 7

```
$arr = array(
      1 => array(1, 2),
      2 => array(1,2,3),
      3 => array(4,8)
    );
echo (count($arr, COUNT_RECURSIVE) - count($arr));
```