# Count all values in nested arrays using recursion in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I want to learn how to use recursive functions, so I started to create one:

```
<?php
$tableau = [[[[2],[2]],[[2],[2]]],[[[2],[2]],[[2],[2]]]];
function test_count_recursive($tab, $compte = 0){
    foreach($tab as $ss_tab){
        if(!is_array($ss_tab)){
            $compte += 1;
        }
        else{
            test_count_recursive($ss_tab, $compte);
        }
    }
    return $compte;
}

echo test_count_recursive($tableau);
```

But it doesn't work, can you tell me why?

Comment: Your returning $compte but not using it.

Comment: [Php recursive array counting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18429958/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you pass a piece of data up the recursive call tree or down, not both. In this case, you don't need to pass parent values down. Just return the count and let the parent node accumulate it:

```
<?php

function test_count_recursive($tab /* one param only */) {
    $compte = 0; // <-- store the local total for this node

    foreach ($tab as $ss_tab) {
        if (is_array($ss_tab)) {
            $compte += test_count_recursive($ss_tab /* one param only */);
            // ^^^^^^^ accumulate total from children
        }
        else {
            $compte++;
        }
    }

    return $compte;
}

$tableau = [[[[2],[2]],[[2],[2]]],[[[2],[2]],[[2],[2]]]];   
echo test_count_recursive($tableau); // => 8
```

Comment: Thank you this feels very counterintuitive for the moment but it's perfect.